# Elastic Search Fielddata error in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am a very noob and very very very beginner in elastic search, I got this error

```
StatusCodeError: [illegal_argument_exception] Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [time-stamp] in order to load field data in memory by reversing the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.
```

I saw a few blogs where they mentioned I have to do something like

```
"field": "user.keyword"
```

but I tried to put this 1 line snippet in my code, please help me out I don't even know what is field and user in my case/code

my code:

```
esClient.search({
            index:ESindex,

            body: {
              sort:[{"time-stamp":{"order":"desc"}}],
              size:req.query.count,
              query: {
                  match_phrase: { "participant-id":req.query["participant-id"] }
              }
              }
          })
```

Comment: can you please post your index mapping ?

Comment: i am taking data from kibana,so i am pasting kibana data in jsonn format                   ```{
  "_index": "web",
  "_type": "event",
  "_id": "web+0+93",
  "_version": 93,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "csg-id": "",
    "event-details": {
      "web-parameter": "",
      "web-type": "navigation"
    },
    "participant-id": "20bb7c81-4451-42e7-8d3c-e06279ee7fd9",
  }
}```is this what you are asking for?

Comment: use `GET web` api and put response of it in your question.